# Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = failed to get sandbox image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6

Tags: kubernetes

Today I found some events in kubernetes(`v1.28.3`) cluster, this error event look like this:

```
(combined from similar events): Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = failed to get sandbox image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to pull image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to pull and unpack image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to resolve reference "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6": failed to do request: Head "https://us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/v2/k8s-artifacts-prod/images/pause/manifests/3.6": dial tcp 74.125.204.82:443: i/o timeout
```

I know it may be a network issue when download the `registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6` image, but I could not found the image `registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6` config in the deamon set, this is the yaml define:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: calico-node
  namespace: calico-system
  annotations:
    deprecated.daemonset.template.generation: '1'
status:
  currentNumberScheduled: 2
  numberMisscheduled: 0
  desiredNumberScheduled: 2
  numberReady: 1
  observedGeneration: 1
  updatedNumberScheduled: 2
  numberAvailable: 1
  numberUnavailable: 1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: calico-node
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: calico-node
        k8s-app: calico-node
      annotations:
        hash.operator.tigera.io/cni-config: 9f0a12e03c58671de56ed3876cb88f1c43cef5dc
        hash.operator.tigera.io/system: bb4746872201725da2dea19756c475aa67d9c1e9
        hash.operator.tigera.io/tigera-ca-private: 8766b9b7cef0ba4722da2eb519044c7c3b68df33
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: lib-modules
          hostPath:
            path: /lib/modules
            type: ''
        - name: xtables-lock
          hostPath:
            path: /run/xtables.lock
            type: FileOrCreate
        - name: policysync
          hostPath:
            path: /var/run/nodeagent
            type: DirectoryOrCreate
        - name: tigera-ca-bundle
          configMap:
            name: tigera-ca-bundle
            defaultMode: 420
        - name: node-certs
          secret:
            secretName: node-certs
            defaultMode: 420
        - name: var-run-calico
          hostPath:
            path: /var/run/calico
            type: ''
        - name: var-lib-calico
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/calico
            type: ''
        - name: cni-bin-dir
          hostPath:
            path: /opt/cni/bin
            type: ''
        - name: cni-net-dir
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/cni/net.d
            type: ''
        - name: cni-log-dir
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log/calico/cni
            type: ''
        - name: flexvol-driver-host
          hostPath:
            path: /usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec/nodeagent~uds
            type: DirectoryOrCreate
      initContainers:
        - name: flexvol-driver
          image: docker.io/calico/pod2daemon-flexvol:v3.26.1
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: flexvol-driver-host
              mountPath: /host/driver
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
            privileged: true
            runAsUser: 0
            runAsGroup: 0
            runAsNonRoot: false
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
            seccompProfile:
              type: RuntimeDefault
        - name: install-cni
          image: docker.io/calico/cni:v3.26.1
          command:
            - /opt/cni/bin/install
          env:
            - name: CNI_CONF_NAME
              value: 10-calico.conflist
            - name: SLEEP
              value: 'false'
            - name: CNI_NET_DIR
              value: /etc/cni/net.d
            - name: CNI_NETWORK_CONFIG
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: cni-config
                  key: config
            - name: KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST
              value: 10.96.0.1
            - name: KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT
              value: '443'
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: cni-bin-dir
              mountPath: /host/opt/cni/bin
            - name: cni-net-dir
              mountPath: /host/etc/cni/net.d
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
            privileged: true
            runAsUser: 0
            runAsGroup: 0
            runAsNonRoot: false
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
            seccompProfile:
              type: RuntimeDefault
      containers:
        - name: calico-node
          image: docker.io/calico/node:v3.26.1
          env:
            - name: DATASTORE_TYPE
              value: kubernetes
            - name: WAIT_FOR_DATASTORE
              value: 'true'
            - name: CLUSTER_TYPE
              value: k8s,operator,bgp
            - name: CALICO_DISABLE_FILE_LOGGING
              value: 'false'
            - name: FELIX_DEFAULTENDPOINTTOHOSTACTION
              value: ACCEPT
            - name: FELIX_HEALTHENABLED
              value: 'true'
            - name: FELIX_HEALTHPORT
              value: '9099'
            - name: NODENAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: spec.nodeName
            - name: NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            - name: FELIX_TYPHAK8SNAMESPACE
              value: calico-system
            - name: FELIX_TYPHAK8SSERVICENAME
              value: calico-typha
            - name: FELIX_TYPHACAFILE
              value: /etc/pki/tls/certs/tigera-ca-bundle.crt
            - name: FELIX_TYPHACERTFILE
              value: /node-certs/tls.crt
            - name: FELIX_TYPHAKEYFILE
              value: /node-certs/tls.key
            - name: FIPS_MODE_ENABLED
              value: 'false'
            - name: FELIX_TYPHACN
              value: typha-server
            - name: CALICO_MANAGE_CNI
              value: 'true'
            - name: CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR
              value: 10.96.0.0/12
            - name: CALICO_IPV4POOL_VXLAN
              value: CrossSubnet
            - name: CALICO_IPV4POOL_BLOCK_SIZE
              value: '26'
            - name: CALICO_IPV4POOL_NODE_SELECTOR
              value: all()
            - name: CALICO_IPV4POOL_DISABLE_BGP_EXPORT
              value: 'false'
            - name: CALICO_NETWORKING_BACKEND
              value: bird
            - name: IP
              value: autodetect
            - name: IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD
              value: first-found
            - name: IP6
              value: none
            - name: FELIX_IPV6SUPPORT
              value: 'false'
            - name: KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST
              value: 10.96.0.1
            - name: KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT
              value: '443'
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: tigera-ca-bundle
              readOnly: true
              mountPath: /etc/pki/tls/certs
            - name: tigera-ca-bundle
              readOnly: true
              mountPath: /etc/pki/tls/cert.pem
              subPath: ca-bundle.crt
            - name: lib-modules
              readOnly: true
              mountPath: /lib/modules
            - name: xtables-lock
              mountPath: /run/xtables.lock
            - name: policysync
              mountPath: /var/run/nodeagent
            - name: node-certs
              readOnly: true
              mountPath: /node-certs
            - name: var-run-calico
              mountPath: /var/run/calico
            - name: var-lib-calico
              mountPath: /var/lib/calico
            - name: cni-log-dir
              mountPath: /var/log/calico/cni
            - name: cni-net-dir
              mountPath: /host/etc/cni/net.d
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /liveness
              port: 9099
              host: localhost
              scheme: HTTP
            timeoutSeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/calico-node
                - '-bird-ready'
                - '-felix-ready'
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /bin/calico-node
                  - '-shutdown'
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
            privileged: true
            runAsUser: 0
            runAsGroup: 0
            runAsNonRoot: false
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
            seccompProfile:
              type: RuntimeDefault
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 5
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      serviceAccountName: calico-node
      serviceAccount: calico-node
      hostNetwork: true
      securityContext: {}
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      tolerations:
        - key: CriticalAddonsOnly
          operator: Exists
        - operator: Exists
          effect: NoSchedule
        - operator: Exists
          effect: NoExecute
      priorityClassName: system-node-critical
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 0
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
```

where is the pause image configuration? what should I do to find out? I have tried to change the kubelet config and add mirror address like this:

```
[root@k8sslave01 kubelet]# systemctl status kubelet --full
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-02-19 12:26:30 CST; 33min ago
     Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/
 Main PID: 30876 (kubelet)
    Tasks: 11
   Memory: 84.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           └─30876 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock --pod-infra-container-image=registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.6
```

the `registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.6` is the new address. It seems did not work. I have already test the container is accessable:

```
[root@k8sslave01 kubelet]# crictl pull registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.6
Image is up to date for sha256:6270bb605e12e581514ada5fd5b3216f727db55dc87d5889c790e4c760683fee
```

Answer (score 1):

I also catch this issue, steps as bellow can fix it.

1. docker pull docker/desktop-kubernetes-pause:3.8
2. docker images
   you'll see result like bellow:

> docker/desktop-kubernetes-pause 3.8 4873874c08ef 19 months ago 711kB

// tag pause to registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8
3. docker tag 4873874c08ef registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8

// import pause to containerd
4. ctr -n k8s.io images import pause.tar
5. sudo ctr -n k8s.io images import pause.tar

Then restart kubelet, after kubelet daemon is active and healthy, you can reset k8s cluster, and reinstall k8s again.

Comment: I have already tried like this, but this image will reset in the furture and I have to do this steps again.

Comment: Maybe add proxy settings or set a proper repository for containerd can help.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to solve this issue by change the containerd sandbox image:

```
version = 2
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri"]
  #sandbox_image = "k8s.m.daocloud.io/pause:3.6"
  sandbox_image = "registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.6"
```

replace the `sandbox_image` to any mirror address you can access.